# enum in prisma instead of table

Tags: prisma

I have two tables in my Prisma db. One is for admins and the other is for users, and since they differ a lot from each other I decided not to create an isAdmin field. They have both in common the establishment that is described as a table (one-to-many relation), but it has only one field (name). I'd like to know whether it is a good idea to create an Enum to represent this field. My only doubt is that, since the values of the enums can change (adding more fields dynamically), it is not as good as creating a table

```
model Admin {
    id              String @id @default(uuid())
    pin             Int
    establishment   Establishment @relation(fields: [establishmentId], references: [id])
    establishmentId Int
}

model User {
    id String @id @default(uuid())
    name            String
    balance         Float @default(0)
    establishment   Establishment @relation(fields: [establishmentId], references: [id])
    establishmentId Int
}

model Establishment {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
}
```

This is how I've imagined the new data source to be like

```
model Admin {
    id              String @id @default(uuid())
    pin             Int
    establishment   Establishment
}

model User {
    id String @id @default(uuid())
    name            String
    balance         Float @default(0)
    establishment   Establishment
}

enum Establishment {
    ESTABLISHMENT1
    ESTABLISHMENT2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you won't need to store any more fields for Establishment then the enums approach is good. But in case in future you are envisioning that there could be other common fields, then you would need to duplicate them in Users and Admins Table and Enums approach won't be a fit.

Another approach could be to use the check constraint on database level to only allow two valid values i.e. ESTABLISHMENT1 and ESTABLISHMENT2, this way you won't even need to define enums.